# How to insert multiple records into database table using gridview in asp.net using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I wish to develope an asp page using vb.net, using which one can insert more than one records
at a time for example **"Item Order Placing form"**  in which one can place more than one order and can see its whole order also so how can it be possible using gridview with vb.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You should really try first... and then post code you have a problem with. One possible solution would be to have a listview or gridview and an area below where the person enters each order item one at a time. When order complete click button. This fill fire code which you need to write that will go through each row and add to db.